# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - Django

Tags: python

```
class IndexDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        month = request.GET.get('month', None)
        current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
        target_month = month if month is not None else current_month
        print(target_month,type(target_month))
```

I am getting this error :

```
Internal Server Error: /api/user/index/
.......
.......
  File "C:\Users\77922\PycharmProjects\Axepanda\user\views.py", line 34, in get
    print(target_month,type(target_month))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Hey guys,the error occurred when I wrote this "`type(target_month)`"
Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: Do you have something else called `type` somewhere else in your file?

Comment: You have most likely used `type` or `print` as a variable name, thus overriding the built-in function of that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned `type` to a string. Don't assign a variable to a built-in variable name. If you `print(type)` and it outputs a string, you'll know for sure.

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. __If you want to say "thank you," vote and accept that person's answer__. _READ_: [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).